# How To Configure WSO2 API Manager version 4.0.0 with Analytics version 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 API Manager Version 4.0.0 is Working Fine With Choreo Analytics but Is there Any Way to Configure API Manager Version 4.0.0 with API-M Analytics Version 3.2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with API Manager 4.0.0.

The API Manager v4.0.0 has gone through a lot of architectural changes and the Handlers and implementations related to publishing Analytics Data to the APIM Analytics server have been removed. Therefore, with my understanding, it is not possible to achieve the same in the v4.0.0 environment.

Answer (score 1):

With the API Manager 4.0 release, the API Analytics was completely revamped and offered as a cloud-based analytics solution to provide users with an unparalleled analytics experience. Therefore, integrating APIM Analytics 3.2.0 with APIM 4.0.0 is not a possible/advisable solution due to architectural constraints.